# When I use Jmeter3.3 to excuse Distributed stress testing，I can't connect to the remote server

Tags: jmeter

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
>   nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:54)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.(ClientJMeterEngine.java:67)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.createEngine(DistributedRunner.java:237)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.getClientEngine(DistributedRunner.java:213)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:93)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:86)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    ... 28 more 2017-11-28 20:12:51,444 INFO
>   o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to configure localhost 2017-11-28
>   20:12:51,444 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote
>   engine: 192.168.20.16 2017-11-28 20:12:51,528 INFO
>   o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 192.168.20.142
>   2017-11-28 20:12:54,604 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring
>   remote engine: 192.168.20.57 2017-11-28 20:12:54,711 INFO
>   o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Stopping remote engines 2017-11-28
>   20:12:54,711 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: about to stop remote
>   test on 192.168.20.57 2017-11-28 20:12:54,745 ERROR
>   o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine:  java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.rstopTest(RemoteJMeterEngineImpl.java:198)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.rstopTest(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.stopTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:84)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.stop(DistributedRunner.java:157)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.stop(DistributedRunner.java:174)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:111)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:86)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>   [?:1.8.0_111]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_111]     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
>   2017-11-28 20:12:54,745 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: about to stop
>   remote test on 192.168.20.142

Comment: All JMeter slaves should have same 3.3 version

Comment: yes,I used 3 slaves with the same version

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you define `java.rmi.server.hostname` and `server_port` system properties either via -D command-line argument or by putting the appropriate values into *system.properties* file.
2. Make sure that port 1099 is open and you can reach JMeter server from the slaves and vice versa using [telnet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx) or equivalent
3. Enable logging on JMeter slaves by passing the desired log file name and path via [`-j` command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

If nothing help - update your question including all the defined properties, command lines to start server and slaves and log files.

References:

- [java.rmi Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)